# Scala/Slick working with additional columns in model that won't be persisited

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

I've been asking myself if there's a way to work with additional columns defined in the model that don't have corresponding columns in the `db`. For example: I have a table called `List` and another table called `Item`. The connection between those two table is `List --N----------1-- Item`. One `List` may have n items but one `Item` is only assigned to one `List`.
Those are the models: 
[image]
As you can see the attribute `list` in my `Item` model is a foreign key to `id` on `List`. 
The reason for me to want an extra attribute `items` on my `List` model that isn't represented in the `db` might become clear in this example:

```
    def getListsByLC(lcId: Int): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async {
    listRepo.getListsByLC(lcId).flatMap { lists =>
      val newLists: Seq[Future[Seq[List]]] = lists.map(list => {
         val items: Future[Seq[Item]] = itemRepo.getItemsByList(list.id).map { items =>
           list.items.get ++ items //This is where the error occurs
        }

        items.map(i => lists)
      })

      Future.sequence(newLists).map(_.flatten).map(lists => Ok(Json.obj("lists" -> lists)))
    }
  }
```

Say I want to return all the `Lists` in my `db` with all the corresponding `Items` in it. I don't want to just pass the two `seq` and connect them in the `Front-end`. I'd like to add/merge the `Seq[Item]` to my `items` attribute in `List`.

This is how I map the attributes to my model:

```
private class ListTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[List](tag, "Lists") {

    type Data = (Int, String, Date, Date, Int)

    def constructList: Data => List = {
      case (id, name, createdAt, updatedAt, lc) => List(id, name, createdAt, updatedAt, lc)
    }

    def extractList: PartialFunction[List, Data] = {
      case List(id, name, createdAt, updatedAt, lc, _) => (id, name, createdAt, updatedAt, lc)
    }

    def id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

    def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("name")

    def createdAt: Rep[Date] = column[Date]("createdAt")

    def updatedAt: Rep[Date] = column[Date]("updatedAt")

    def lc: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("lc")

    def lcFK: ForeignKeyQuery[ListTable, List] = foreignKey("list_FK", lc, lists)(_.id, onUpdate = ForeignKeyAction.Restrict, onDelete = ForeignKeyAction.Cascade)

    def * : ProvenShape[List] = (id, name, createdAt, updatedAt, lc) <> (constructList, extractList.lift)
  }
```

My code compiles but throws an error at runtime:
[image]

Frankly, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong and I don't seem to find any other examples of people doing something similar. What I'm trying to do shouldn't be that hard, right? Am I missing something crucial? Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: change to `list.items.getOrElse(Nil) ++ items`

Comment: You can make List class without items, to map it exactly as it is in db, and then make another class ListWithItems with items. Make sure you have foreign key in Items table, referenced to a List table. Then you can map it like                                                                                                 `for {
    list <- listDao.getById(ID)
    items <- itemsDao.filter(_.list === list.id)
} yield (ListWithItems(list.id, list.name, list.createdAt, list.updatedAt, items))`